# Can't we write and execute JavaScript code in a file and see output in console?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I installed JavaScript development tools in eclipse and want to write code in eclipse IDE and see the result.Is it possible to see the result without the browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a javascript code using nodeJS, Provided you are not using any API's that require a browser environment (i.e for example you should not use any DOM manipulating api's in your code).

Steps to follow: 
1)Write your code using a simple text editor and save the file with ".js" extension 
2)Install nodeJS software 
3)open command prompt and execute the command - node filename.js

NodeJS is a javascript runtime built on Chrome's V8 Javascript engine.